# How to design a ANN for signal processing properly?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, signal-processing, pattern-recognition

I don't really understand how I should implement following problem with help of ANN:

Let's say I have a few data sets, which represent the force on a car. (The test car drives on a special road with simulated road damages. All in all there are 8 different ones).

Now I want to train my model to recognize these road damages on data from cars, which drive on normal roads. That's the goal.

The question for me is, how do I classify the road damages correctly for the ANN?

Should I just cut out the special patterns of the road damages and feed my ANN with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to traing an ANN for a any specific task you generally have to complete the following steps:

1. Define the problem
2. Collect and correctly arrange training data
3. Design a suitable network topology
4. Train the network
5. Validate the training result on real data

That means for your case:

1. It seems like you are dealing with a binary classification problem. For a given sensor input you want to predict either damaged or not damaged.
2. You arrange your data as input-target pairs. Input is your sensor data (probably with some temporal context) and output is for example either 1 for damaged and 0 for not damaged.
3. If you are dealing with temporal sensor data you should check out recurrent neural network or convolutional neural network topologies (or a combination of both). Design your network to have the input layer the same amount of neurons as the dimension of your input data and the output layer with a single neuron with a sigmoid activation.
4. This step should then be straight-forward depending on the libraries you use
5. Finally, you can validate the result with some new real sensor data and check if the predictions match your expectations

You will probably need some iterations of step 3-5 until you come up with a well working classifier.

Comment: ok thanks for ur reply. But let's say I have 8 different road damages (crack on the road etc..) , then I will have 8 output neurons, right? And in these neurons I will have a sigmoid activation?

Comment: if you want to predict several classes you need the same amount of output neurons. Most commonly you would use a softmax activations in your last layer in this case.

Comment: ok thx. Another question to step 2 (Collect and correctly arrange training data): To train the model I need to arrange the data and show the model which failures exist. If we take the example with the test road and the car : On every lap I get 1D signal which represents the forces on the car. On certain forces I can say there is ,for example, a hole in the road. How do I exactly tell this to my model? I can theoretically cut out these special patterns out of the signals and provide them to my model?

Comment: for every kind of road damage you will need some examples of the input signal. so you need multiple "input->road damage type" pairs. That is the data the model will learn from. You will probably need a lot of those. It appears to me that you are pretty new to the topic. My advice is to make the first model as simple as possible. Just predict "damaged- not damaged" first. if it works then make the model predict the damage more precisely. Thats the best way to learn and get familiar with the whole NN training topic.